# How to add a delay to an ajax request to avoid performance issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeahead.js

I have a function which returns a certain amount of data triggered in AJAX when typing. Each time it will go to the Oracle DB and fetch the data and show the output.

But, as soon as I type a "long" string like "hello my name is", it launches a single request each time I type a key (10 requests at a single time) and it takes 5 seconds to get 1 request response.

This is causing performance issue in my application. How could I avoid that please?

I have already tried dynamic and delay which are not working. I am using typeahead 2 (typeahead-bs2.min.js).

```
$( "#customer_description" ).typeahead({

 dynamic: true,
 delay: 5000,
 source: function (query, process) {
      $.ajax({
           url: '/data/customer.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'JSON',
           //contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",                        
           data: {
                       all: query,
                   },
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                process(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Delay doesn't help. It would still do 10 queries, just later. Think about the input. Should the string match some criteria before the query is made, such as a min length, or maybe run the query when typing is done etc..

Comment: Which version of typeahead is this?  Are you able to use [a more recent version](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you're saying that you have something like a search input that triggers an Ajax call and you want to hold back that Ajax so it does not trigger for every key you press. Am I right?

Something like:

```
    var timeOutId;
    $("#customer_description").typeahead({
        dynamic: true,
        source: function (query, process) {
            //if there's no ajax call running (the timeout was cleared)...
            if (!timeOutId || 'undefined' === typeof timeOutId) {
                timeOutId = setTimeout(ajaxCall, 300)
            }
        }
    });

    function ajaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/customer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            //contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",                        
            data: {
                all: query,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                process(data);
            },
            complete: function(){
              //when the ajax finishes (success or not) clear the interval
              clearTimeout(timeOutId);
            }
        });
    }
```

You can improve this code doing an "static class" (an object with functions) or pseudoclasses, but that is up to you. This way you can change the timeout for a flag or something, you can add a string length check... or whatever you can think of.

Comment: Hi Astaroth, Thanks for the valuable reply. But I when I am using this approach, the scope of the variable "query" is not validating properly. I have tried some ways to defines these variables, but then I am not getting the desired output. It would be grateful if you could help me with an answer for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the main post and show the code where you delcare that query variable? Maybe it's just that you need to declare it in a higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a request after a 1.5/2 sec gap once the user has stopped typing plus check for the input length as suggested by [Sami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3279876/sami).

Along with that to avoid sending multiple requests you can always abort the previous request and send a new one.

```
 var start = new Date()
 ,end, request;

 $('input:text').on('change', function(){
  end = new Date();
  var input = $(this).val();
  var diff = (end - start)/1000;

  //checking for a 1.5 sec delay and input length
  //You can adjust the delay time, I have kept it as 1.5seconds
  if(diff > 1.5 && input.length > 5){
    if (request !== undefined){
      //aborting the previous request
      request.abort();
    }
    start = new Date();

    //storing the ajax request in a variable so that it can be aborted later when we fire a new request

    request = $.ajax({
      url: '/data/customer.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      //contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",                        
      data: {
      all: query,
      },
      success: function(data) {
               //console.log(data);
                 process(data);
              }
    });
   }
 });
```